# Function with dynamic return in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to create an API on NodeJS with typescript

I have the following interfaces :

```
export interface ISqlResonse<T> {
success?:   string
error?:     string
data:       Array<T> //Nothing | array of object when are db operations
}

export interface IApiResponse<T> {
status:     'error' | 'success'
message:    string
data:       Array<T>
}
```

Each api call call a function that call an generic class name DB that select/insert/update/delate data from an database
For example the update function look like :

```
 async updateData(input: IUpdateParam) : Promise<ISqlResonse<object>> {
    ...
    ...
}
```

API function call DB and look like :

```
async update(req): Promise<IApiResponse<IAccessPointsTableStructure>> {
    let data        = req.body ;
    let updateObj   = {
        data ,
        table: 'accessPoints',
        excludeColumns: 'loggedUserId',
        additionalColumns: { modifiedBy: '1', modifiedAt: crtDate },
        validationRules,
        where: `id=${data.id}`,
        returningData: true
    }

    let sqlResults = await db.updateData(updateObj) ; //  !!!

    if(typeof sqlResults.error==="string") {
        logger.log('error','Error on updating Access Points!',{sql: db.getQuery(), error: sqlResults.error});
        return({status:'error',message: 'Error on updating Access Points!',data: sqlResults.data});
    }

    logger.log('success', 'Access Points data updated with success!');
    return({status: 'error', message: 'Access Points data updated with success!', data: sqlResults.data})
}
```

My question is : how can I call the function db.updateData() and tell this function that I want to receive in data from ISqlResponse an array with objects like interface IAccessPointsTableStructure.

With other words i want to control the returning type of function. I teste several times with different approaches . (Replace  wit  in db.updateData(...) <..>...
Thank you in advice.

Comment: Cast the return value: `<IApiResponse<IAccessPointsTableStructure>>(await db.updateData(updateObj))`? Maybe I am misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't included the definition of `IUpdateParam`, but I will assume that its `table` property is what decides the type of thing `updateData()` returns.  Everywhere I've commented "guess" is just for example; you should change them to fit your use cases.

---

You should be able to modify the signature for the `updateData()` to reflect the relationship between the type of `IUpdateParam` passed in and the type of `Promise<ISqlResponse<{}>>` returned.  Here's one way to do it, using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) (you could use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) instead).  First, declare a type to represent the mapping between the table names and the data type for each table.  For example:

```
export type TableNameToTypeMapping = {
  accessPoints: IAccessPointsTableStructure,
  otherThings: IOtherThingsTableStructure, // guess
  // ...
}
```

Now, you can change the definition of `IUpdateParam` so that it only accepts the right values for `table`:

```
export interface IUpdateParam<K extends keyof TableNameToTypeMapping> {
        data: any, // guess
        table: K, 
        excludeColumns: string, // guess
        additionalColumns: any, // guess
        validationRules: any, // guess
        where: string // guess
}
```

So an `IUpdateParam<'accessPoints'>` object is meant to deal with the `accessPoints` table, and it is different from an `IUpdateParam<'otherThings'>` object.

Now the signature for `updateData()` can be changed to:

```
async updateData<K extends keyof TableNameToTypeMapping>(
  input: IUpdateParam<K>
): Promise<ISqlResonse<TableNameToTypeMapping[K]>> {
    // implement this!  The implementation is likely not
    // type-safe unless you use runtime type guards
  }
```

This means if you call `updateData` with a parameter of type `IUpdateParam<'accessPoints'>`, you will get back a `Promise<ISqlResponse<TableNameToTypeMapping['accessPoints']>>`.  But `TableNameToTypeMapping['accessPoints']` is just `IAccessPointsTableStructure`, so you are getting back a `Promise<ISqlResponse<IAccessPointsTableStructure>>` as desired.

---

Note that the object literal `updateObj` will have its `table` property inferred as type `string`, which is too wide.  To make sure the call to `updateData()` works as desired, you will either need to assert that the `updateObj.table` property is of literal type `'accessPoints'`, like this:

```
let updateObj = {
    data,
    table: 'accessPoints' as 'accessPoints', // assertion
    excludeColumns: 'loggedUserId',
    additionalColumns: { modifiedBy: '1', modifiedAt: crtDate },
    validationRules,
    where: `id=${data.id}`,
    returningData: true
}
```

or you will need to declare that `updateObj` is of type `IUpdateParam<'accessPoints'>`, like this:

```
// type declaration
let updateObj:IUpdateParam<'accessPoints'> = {
    data ,
    table: 'accessPoints',
    excludeColumns: 'loggedUserId',
    additionalColumns: { modifiedBy: '1', modifiedAt: crtDate },
    validationRules,
    where: `id=${data.id}`,
    returningData: true
}
```

Either way should work.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment . Generics seems to solve my issue.